# Nodejs request socket object parameter

Tags: node.js, sockets, request

Sorry if I ask silly question, I am working with the example below regarding on nodejs long polling.
http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/12/02/diving-into-node-js-a-long-polling-example/

I understand most of them, but just one thing I am not quite able to understand although I have done thousands of searching.

```
fs.stat('filepath', function(err, stats) {
    // if the file is changed
    if (stats.mtime.getTime() > request.socket._idleStart.getTime()) {
        // read it
        fs.readFile('filepath', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            // return the contents
            response.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type'   : 'text/plain',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
            });

            // return response
            response.write(data, 'utf8');
            response.end();

            // return
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

The part "request.socket._idleStart", what is the meaning of the parameter _idleStart? Actually, I try to print out the whole request object and got the following parameters.

```
_readableState: 
   { highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: [],
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: false,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     calledRead: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     objectMode: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _maxListeners: 10,
  socket: 
....
...
...
```

I am wondering if there is any documentations describing these parameters, thanks for all for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

those parameters with `_` underscore, are used for maintaining the state of socket, its not meant for working with them. there are functions that are more reliable than those.

from node.js documentation

> readable._read
>
> Note: This function should NOT be called directly. It should be
>   implemented by child classes, and called by the internal Readable
>   class methods only.
>
> All Readable stream implementations must provide a _read method to
>   fetch data from the underlying resource.
>
> This method is prefixed with an underscore because it is internal to
>   the class that defines it, and should not be called directly by user
>   programs. However, you are expected to override this method in your
>   own extension classes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I understand correctly, those values have functions to retrieve them instead of letting me to call directly, right?

Comment: @user2499325 yes correct, imagine "private" variables you can never access except from a public function. Note, that functions like `.read()` depend on these variables, for appropriate behavior, changing values directly might result to something unexpected.